# C# - KeyNotFoundException on Initialization of Dictionary with List<string> values

Tags: c#

A KeyNotFoundException ("The given key was not present in the dictionary") is being thrown upon initialization of a static dictionary. The code is as follows:

```
public class Test {

    static public Dictionary<string,List<string>> dictionary = new Dictionary<string,List<string>>() {

        ["key1"] = {"testing","testingagain"},
        ["key2"] = {"testing","testingagain"}
    };
}
```

However, if the dictionary is initialized using List constructors explicitly, it is successful:

```
public class Test {

    static public Dictionary<string,List<string>> works = new Dictionary<string,List<string>>() {

        ["key1"] = new List<string>() {"testing","testingagain"},
        ["key2"] = new List<string>() {"testing","testingagain"}
    };
}
```

I would think that since the first one compiles fine the compiler would know that they are `List<string>` objects, and the examples would give the same results. Why are they not?

Comment: Can you also add the code that tries to find the key?

Comment: @Tony, all you need to do is `var test = new Test();`.

Comment: I believe the reason is that you can only use initializer expressions to assign to an existing type. For a new item, you need to use a `new` expression instead. But why the compiler doesn't complain about this at design time is beyond me...

Comment: It looks like collection initializers can be used on nested collections, but currently this isn't documented: https://github.com/dotnet/docs/issues/4686

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because `List<T>` implements `IEnumerable` and contains a definition for `Add`, alongside with how the collection-initializers work in C#, the declaration is valid at compile-time, but again since you've not actually initialized the `List<string>` it becomes invalid at run-time due to memory allocation.

Answer (score -1):

Because a list has to get „created“ so whenever you do something with a list you have to use `new List<t>()`

Else the list is null so you cant put stuff in it.